# Best way to de-scale my home (gas) water heater?

Tags: water-heater, maintenance, anode

I recently did the recommended yearly draining of our home (gas) water heater. I opened the pressure relief valve to bleed air into the tank so that it could drain. After putting everything back, I found that the (now closed) pressure relief valve was leaking. Removing it, I noticed that it was badly fouled with scale, so I replaced it with a new one.

While I had the old relief valve off, I noticed what seemed like excessive buildup of scale on the inside of the tank as well. I'm not necessarily a good judge of what's "excessive", but it was more than I expected for a tank that was only around five years old.

I thought it might be a good idea to de-scale (or reduce-scale) the tank, so I looked online and learned that there seem to be two approaches: (1) replacing the tank anode, and (2) using a chemical de-scaling agent.

My impression is that a new anode reduces *future* deposits, but maybe doesn't do much about existing deposits(?). I would imagine that adding a chemical de-scaling agent to a full tank ought to be inexpensive and very effective against existing scale, but the rarity of google hits for any such residential-use chemical de-scaling products has me wondering.

**Can someone who has experience doing this kind of thing with residential water heaters weigh in on pros/cons of doing either/both?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to be aggressive, use 4:1 muriatic acid mix. 4 parts water and one part muriatic acid. Let it work for 1 or more hours.